textstat_simil not found
I am using a script that contains the function textstat_simil and when I run it it throws an error "could not find function "textstat_simil"
similarity_matrix <- textstat_simil(x = sample_dfm,
                                margin = 'documents',
                                method = 'jaccard',
                                min_simil = 0.85)

I have tried to reinstall quanteda, and it still doesn't find it. Even when I navigate through the help page, and click on the similarities link from the viewer, it says 'URL '/help/library/quanteda.textstats/help/textstat_simil' not found'
This doesn't happen with other quanteda funcion. Any ideas?
Thanks very much!

So you've installed the package.  Good.  Did you load it before calling teststat_simil?  (You do this with library(quanteda).)  In either case, we need a minimal, reproducible example that shows us exactly what you did.   Start with a clean session.  Load the package, define your data, call the function, demonstrate the error.

textstat_simil is part of quanteda.textstats you have to install :
### Install
install.packages("quanteda.textstats")
### Load
library(quanteda.textstats)


